# VB Login for website using MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am learning VB and trying to create a website. It requires Login. So i created a login form and the in the VB file i have written the following codes.

```
          Imports System.Data.Odbc
          Partial Public Class login_2
          Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Shared login_username As Object
Shared login_password As Object

Protected Sub LogIn_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs)
    Dim cn As New OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=hotel_test; User=root;Password=Amir1234;")
    cn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("Select * from tbl_login where username=? and password=?", cn)

    'Add parameters to get the username and password  

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_name", OdbcType.VarChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@user_name").Value = login_2.login_username.ToString

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@password").Value = login_2.login_password.ToString

    Dim dr As OdbcDataReader
    ' Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
    ' If row exists, the login is successful  

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader



End Sub

End Class
```

I am using the Visual Studio and when i am trying to run the form, it displays the following error.

```
        Server Error in '/' Application.
    Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type                            'System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs'.          
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web    request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and       where it originated in the code.

 Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type           'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs'.
```

Source Error:

```
    <div class="submit">
    <asp:Button Text="Log in" runat="server" OnClick="LogIn_Clicked" />
```

Seeking for help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your HTML references an `asp:button`, but the code behind appears to be leftover from an `asp:login` `OnAuthenticate` request.

If you are no longer using the `asp:login` control, then the simple solution is to fix the event signature:

```
Protected Sub LogIn_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

If, on the other hand, you really meant to use the login control, then you need to fix the HTML from

```
<asp:Button Text="Log in" runat="server" OnClick="LogIn_Clicked" />
```

to something like:

```
<asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="LogIn_Clicked" />
```

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on the Login control.